# Issue with my CSS and making my game look the same and user-friendly on different screen sizes

Tags: css, flexbox

Running into a big issue with my game when I switch devices. Tried playing around with FlexBox but every step I take I make the situation worse. My project is due in a few days: what should I do? Easy fixes you can recommend? Anything I can do to change it and making it more responsive on different screens? THANKS

```
.grid {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(8, 8, 0);
  margin-left: 850px;
  border-top: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-left: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-right: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00ffff;
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 90px #da0dcf;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px #00ffff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00ffff;
  }
}

.mini-grid {
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-top: 320px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
  border-top: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-left: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-right: 10px solid #00ffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ffff;
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 90px #da0dcf;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00ffff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #15ff00;
  }
}


.mini-grid div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}


.grid div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.shape {
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 241);
}


.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 770px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  top: 200px;
}

h2{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  right: 845px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

.rules {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 500px;
  left: 260px;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;

  background-image: url('wallpaperflare.com_wallpaper.jpg');
  background-position: 300px 80px;
  background-size: cover;  
}

.score {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  
}

.level {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#start-button {
  background-color: #e91f1f;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

#start-button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.shape {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

#level {
  background-color: #2e6e1b;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

#level:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#level7 {
  background-color: #e29750;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

#level7:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#refresh-button {
  background-color: #923385;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#refresh-button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

audio {
  background-color: #086910;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 20px;
}

audio source {
  display: none;
}

audio::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #130707 transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

audio::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color: #141313 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  background-color: rgb(88, 223, 110);
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-pause-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
  display: rgb(238, 236, 236);
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container {
  width: 100px;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #110e0e;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: [ask]..........

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SO! There is no easy fix in your situation as you have been using mostly *fixed units (`px`)*, never considering creating element sizes relative to the main container or viewport size. You could try to `body { transform: scale(..) }` using `@media` queries, but I'm sure that will backfire somehow, somewhere really soon. Flexibility, responsiveness and *fixed units* just don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to provide a specific solution to your question without the HTML structure and the screenshots of the desired look for each screen size. What I could recommend that can help you make your game more responsive:

1. Use relative units: Instead of using fixed pixel values for width, height, margin, and padding use relative units such as percentages, em, or rem. This will ensure that your game adapts to different screen sizes.
2. Use media queries: You can use media queries to define different styles for different screen sizes. For example, you can define different styles for screens smaller than 768px, screens between 768px and 992px, and screens larger than 992px.

But if time is of the essence try to use a CSS framework such as Bootstrap to help you create a responsive layout quickly.

Comment: Since he hasn't provided any information, your answer is only a wild guess. [answer]

Comment: And why is that a wild guess?? I have answered his question: "Anything I can do to change it and making it more responsive on different screens?"

Comment: Your own first sentence is the reason it's a wild guess. The poster is required to provide a [mcve] and they have not done so.